# Simple program crashes for some reason

Tags: c++, crash, calculator

I wrote simple binary calculator,which I'm going to develop.Everything works for a few first calculations,but after that the program chrashes-"Binary.exe has stopped working".I think there might be something wrong with dynamicly allocated array in function "decToBin()",but i can't spot the issue.Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <conio.h>

    using namespace std;

    void binToDec()
    {
    string bin;
    cout<<"Binary code: ";
    cin>>bin;

    int powr = 0;
    int num = 0;
    long long sum = 0;


    for(int i=bin.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(bin[i] == '1')
        {
            num = 2;
        }
        else if(bin[i] == '0')
        {
            num = 0 ;
        }
        sum += pow(num,powr);
        cout<<sum<<endl;

        powr++;
    }
    cout<<"Decimal: "<<sum<<endl;

    sum = 0;
    powr = 0;
    num = 0;
}

void decToBin()
{
    int dec = 0;
    cout<<"Decimal number or digit: ";
    cin>>dec;

    int i = 0;
    int *numBin = new int[i];
    while(dec > 0)
    {
        numBin[i] = dec%2;
        dec = dec/2;
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"Binary: ";
    for(int j = i-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        cout<<numBin[j];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    i = 0;
    delete [] numBin;
}

int main()
{
    //USER INPUT
    int nav = 0;


    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        cout << "1.Binary to decimal:"<<endl;
        cout << "2.Decimal to binary:"<<endl;
        cin>>nav;

        switch(nav)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            binToDec();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            decToBin();
            break;
        }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with `decToBin()`. `numBin` has size 0 yet you add elements to it. Why don't you use any STL containers instead? Also why `math.h` and `conio.h`?

Comment: `int i = 0; int *numBin = new int[i];`   probably not what you intended.  As the line in the loop `numBin[i] = dec%2;` is UB.

Comment: what's STL container i could use?math.h is for pow().

Comment: @figorix this is C++ so anything but raw arrays.  Start with vectors.

Comment: You've got to be kidding, to use the `power` function for converting from binary to decimal.  Research your favorite references for "bit shifting" and "binary AND" (masking).

Comment: i've just didn't know about that.I've just wanted to realize my idea.but thanks for this information,I'll try to change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem:

```
int *numBin = new int[i]; //i is 0, then you add elements to it
```

An easy solution, use `std::vector`:

```
vector<int> numBin;
...
numBin.push_back(dec%2);
```

You don't have to worry about dynamic memory at all now.

Comment: but then in for loop i have to use vector::iterator right?

Comment: @figorix, no the size of the vector auto increases, you can take out i all together.